# Prevent Visual Studio from changing void to Task when adding 'async' to a method (and from appending "Async" to a method's name)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When VS sees that you are `await`ing within a non-async method, it shows you an error.

When selecting to fix that error by adding `async` to the method signature - VS also changes `void` to `Task` (which then has to be manually fixed for event handlers). Is there a way to prevent that?

<sub>VS also appends "Async" to the method name. Is there a way to prevent that? (It was asked here [Visual Studio 2017 force to add "async" at method name when use suggest (Ctrl + .)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42692258/visual-studio-2017-force-to-add-async-at-method-name-when-use-suggest-ctrl) and it looks like we're waiting for MS to fix that. Perhaps it's already fixed?)</sub>

Comment: There is a Quick Actions option `Make method async (stay void)`. It is below regular `Make method async` option.

Comment: I believe that currently you can't prevent name modification. There are no Quick Actions settings and there is no relevant rule in C# Code Style settings in Visual Studio. Although I understand the issue with `Async` suffix, in general it is recommended to use it with asynchronous methods. For more information check [Does the use of the “Async” suffix in a method name depend on whether the 'async' modifier is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951774/does-the-use-of-the-async-suffix-in-a-method-name-depend-on-whether-the-async).

Comment: Using `async void` is generally a bad idea, except in limited situations: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: @PeteGarafano As you can see from the link you've supplied, event handlers are one of those exceptions.

Comment: @LeonidVasilyev I didn't notice that! You can transform your comment into an answer. That's it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To leave `void` as a return type use a Quick Actions option `Make method async (stay void)`. You can't prevent name modification.

[image: Make method async (stay void) Quick Action animation]

There are no Quick Actions settings and there is no relevant rule in C# Code Style settings in Visual Studio. EditorConfig `required_suffix` doesn't help either. Although I understand the issue with `Async` suffix, in general it is recommended to use it with asynchronous methods. For more information check:

- [CodeFix CS4033: Make method async (stay void) adds the Async suffix](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/18467) Roslyn issue on GitHub
- [Does the use of the “Async” suffix in a method name depend on whether the 'async' modifier is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951774/does-the-use-of-the-async-suffix-in-a-method-name-depend-on-whether-the-async)
- [Naming Conventions for EditorConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/editorconfig-naming-conventions) article on MSDN.